# Remove the primary link tabs from ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I've managed to get rid of the "Dashboard" link but I can't find how to get rid of the "Admin Users" or "My Model" links. I've Googled and asked around to no avail. Do I just have to hide this stuff with CSS? Seems like a janky solution.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, you can simply add `menu false` to each resource you don't want to show up: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#customize_the_menu